# Ubuntu web browser in 16.04 makes my system hang

Tags: 16.04, webbrowser-app

I have a [Dell precision tower 3620 desktop](http://www.dell.com/us/business/p/precision-t3x20-series-workstation/pd), with Ubuntu 16.04 installed. It has already annoyed me so many times that Ubuntu web browser (*webbrowser-app*) in 16.04 makes my system hang.

The problem is that whenever I open Ubuntu web browser, the system sometimes hangs, but gets restored back again. However, sometimes it hangs, and nothing works except for the mouse. What left to be done after that is to reboot the system by pressing `ALt` + `Print Scr`+`R`+`E`+`I`+`S`+`U`+`B`

Is this is only because Ubuntu Web browser is buggy or because of something else?

Comment: Not sure if that counts as creepy, just buggy. Are you actually using https://launchpad.net/webbrowser-app (which without really looking I suspect is a phablet (phone) thing), or are you using [Chrom(e/ium)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chromium_(web_browser)), [Web/Epiphany](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epiphany_browser), or[Firefox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firefox) etc?

Comment: I see, that is more proper. Launchpad as mentioned in the question

Answer (score 4):

Ghastly piece of kit on 16.04 amd_64 install  - tried to open it for the first time today resulted in a system freeze

```
sudo apt-get remove webbrowser-app
```

sorted it out.